# Woocommerce manipulate products internaly

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I need the following and i´m turning around the thing but can´t get a clean way on doing it:

Some products needs to belong to x category, if a customer buy one of those products, all the rest of the products behind that category should get outofstock or unpublished.

So i need a way to create a function that could run once a product is sold and then find all those products with same category and change their metadata, in this case i will solve the rest of the thing just changing the outofstock meta, but knowing that i guess i will also be able to edit any other post meta value.

I know how to update a meta value, i can´t imagine how to hook/filter the rest. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the [WooCommerce hooks](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/hooks)?

I would check out the woocommerce_order_status_.$new_status->slug hook for the status completed.  So something like:

```
function the_function($order_id) {
    // get the order object
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'the_function' );
```

Comment: Colud be and yes im gonna test in that way. Thanks

Comment: Yeah sure just to note that in my case i need to change meta data once the customer ends the checkout. So the hook i need to use is: woocommerce_order_status_processing. But yes is that way using order status hooks. Thanks